# How to group by multiple groups and obtain bar plot in both stack and dodge positions in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a following data I'd like to plot:

```
df <- structure(list(age.cat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", 
"25-30", "30-35", "35-40", "40-45", "45-50", "50-55", "55-60", 
"60+"), class = "factor"), sex = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), activity_group = c("Food Process", 
"Household", "Labor", "Manufacture", "Other", "Resource Acq", 
"Food Process", "Household", "Labor", "Manufacture", "Other", 
"Resource Acq", "Food Process", "Household", "Labor", "Manufacture", 
"Other", "Resource Acq", "Food Process", "Household", "Labor", 
"Manufacture", "Other", "Resource Acq"), count = c(97L, 86L, 
12L, 75L, 0L, 68L, 62L, 115L, 15L, 88L, 0L, 68L, 153L, 70L, 2L, 
71L, 0L, 290L, 175L, 150L, 44L, 138L, 0L, 500L), total = c(146L, 
2586L, 34L, 81L, 2767L, 92L, 100L, 2462L, 27L, 95L, 2549L, 121L, 
240L, 2002L, 48L, 116L, 1573L, 362L, 256L, 2450L, 75L, 170L, 
2180L, 836L), prop = c(0.0169996494917631, 0.0150718541885734, 
0.00210304942166141, 0.0131440588853838, 0, 0.0119172800560813, 
0.0115801270078446, 0.0214792678371311, 0.00280164363093015, 
0.0164363093014569, 0, 0.0127007844602167, 0.0352453351762267, 
0.0161253167472932, 0.00046072333563695, 0.0163556784151117, 
0, 0.0668048836673577, 0.0293279705044411, 0.0251382604323781, 
0.0073738897268309, 0.0231271995977878, 0, 0.0837942014412603
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), groups = structure(list(age.cat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", 
"25-30", "30-35", "35-40", "40-45", "45-50", "50-55", "55-60", 
"60+"), class = "factor"), sex = c("0", "1", "0", "1"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:6, 7:12, 13:18, 19:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))

head(df)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
# Groups:   age.cat, sex [1]
  age.cat sex   activity_group count total    prop
  <fct>   <chr> <chr>          <int> <int>   <dbl>
1 0-5     0     Food Process      97   146 0.0170 
2 0-5     0     Household         86  2586 0.0151 
3 0-5     0     Labor             12    34 0.00210
4 0-5     0     Manufacture       75    81 0.0131 
5 0-5     0     Other              0  2767 0      
6 0-5     0     Resource Acq      68    92 0.0119
```

I want to bar plot of `prop` (on y-axis) against `age.cat` (on x-axis) using `ggplot2`. But I can't figure out how to group by `sex` and `activity_group`. First I want to group by `sex` in position "dodge", which I've done using the following code:

```
# Plot
prop %>%
  ggplot(aes(age.cat, prop, fill = sex)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

But I also want each bar to show me the `prop` for `activity_group` in position "stack". Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not a working answer, but I like using https://r-graph-gallery.com as a "picture menu" of sorts for finding how to make most plots in `ggplot2`: the examples there include pictures and the data+code to generate the plot, very useful for learning different methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no combined dodge-and-stack position option in ggplot. The two ways to achieve the appearance of dodge-and-stack are:

1. Sneaky facets: put sex on the x axis and facet by the age category, then reduce the horizontal panel spacing to 0 to make it look as though you have nested x axis categories
2. Pseudo-discrete x axis: Create a numeric x axis and fake the dodging yourself, with breaks and labels made to look like a discrete axis.

The first option is easiest:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(paste0('Sex: ', sex), prop, fill = activity_group)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", alpha = 0.5, color = 'gray50') +
  facet_grid(.~age.cat, switch = 'x') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  scale_x_discrete('Age Category', expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Activity group', palette = 'Dark2') +
  labs(y = 'Proportion') +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = 3),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

[image]

Here's the second option for completeness:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(xpos = as.numeric(age.cat) + 0.3 * (as.numeric(sex) - 0.5)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xpos, prop)) +
  geom_col(aes( fill = activity_group),
           position = "stack", alpha = 0.5, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_text(aes(y = -0.01, label = paste('Sex:', sex)), check_overlap = TRUE,
            fontface = 3, color = 'gray30') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  scale_x_continuous('Age Category',
                     breaks = 1:2, labels = levels(df$age.cat)[1:2]) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Activity group', palette = 'Dark2') +
  labs(y = 'Proportion') +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = 3),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

[image]

Comment: Sneaky facets is my general go-to for this. I like the tidiness you've achieved here Allan with zero spacing!

Answer (score 3):

Also a possibility to use two filtered `geom_col` calls and justify them to each side of the break (here using alpha for `sex` which isn't very neat):

```r
library(tidyverse)

prop %>%
  ggplot(aes(age.cat, prop, fill = activity_group, alpha = sex)) +
  geom_col(data = filter(prop, sex == 0), position = "stack", just = 1, width = 0.4) +
  geom_col(data = filter(prop, sex == 1), position = "stack", just = 0, width = 0.4) +
  scale_alpha_manual(breaks = c("0", "1"), values = c(0.7, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting third option to allow stack-and-dodge (I guess we could call it manual justification dodging) I might try to label the bars rather than using alpha, but I think it still works pretty well.

Comment: Also the option of patterns but I don't generally like these!